# Traer datos de sql a mvc(mas concretamente a la vista)

Tags: html, base-de-datos, mvc

Buenos días a todos pasa lo siguiente tengo que mostrar una vista con los datos de una base de datos de sql filtrados por una variable que estoy trayendo de session y estoy tratando con lo siguiente

```html
@model IEnumerable<Examen.Models.Calificacion>

<table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cedula)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nota)
                            </th>

                            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cedula)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nota)
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
```

ya tengo declarada una clase que me contiene a cedula, fecha y nota

si tienen alguna otra solución les agradeceria

Comment: ¿Te funciona o da algún error? Sí es así, indique qué error le da.

Comment: Dice que la referencia al objeto no esta establecida